# Construction of a possible Lagrangian for the ODE's system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, inverse-problems

Given:

$\begin{cases} x''-(x-(y-z))=0 \\ y''+(x-(y-z))=0 \\ z''-f''y-f'y'=0 \end{cases}$

$x,y,z$ - variables, $f$ - arbitrary time-dependent function

The Helmholtz conditions for this system are not all satisfied. It is difficult to solve the system of Helmholtz equations because of the large dimension. *Is there an alternative way to construct a possible Lagrangian for this system of equations?*

```
eqns = {Subscript[c, 
     12] (Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t] - Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t] + 
       Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2][t]) + 
    Subscript[J, 
     1] (Subscript[\[Phi], 1]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], -Subscript[c, 
      12] (Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t] - Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t] + 
       Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2][t]) + 
    Subscript[J, 2] (Subscript[\[Phi], 2]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t], 
   Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2]''[t] - A''[t] Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t] -
     A'[t] Subscript[\[Phi], 2]'[t]};

g1 = {{D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t]], 
     D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[Phi], 1]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[Phi], 1]''[t]]}, {D[eqns[[2]], 
      Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t]], 
     D[eqns[[2]], Subscript[\[Phi], 1]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[2]], Subscript[\[Phi], 1]''[t]]}, {D[eqns[[3]], 
      Subscript[\[Phi], 1][t]], 
     D[eqns[[3]], Subscript[\[Phi], 1]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[3]], Subscript[\[Phi], 1]''[t]]}} // MatrixForm;

g2 = {{D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]], 
     D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]''[t]]}, {D[eqns[[2]], 
      Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]], 
     D[eqns[[2]], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[2]], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]''[t]]}, {D[eqns[[3]], 
      Subscript[\[Phi], 2][t]], 
     D[eqns[[3]], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[3]], Subscript[\[Phi], 2]''[t]]}} // MatrixForm;

g3 = {{D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2][t]], 
     D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[1]], Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2]''[t]]}, {D[eqns[[2]], 
      Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2][t]], 
     D[eqns[[2]], Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[2]], Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2]''[t]]}, {D[eqns[[3]], 
      Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2][t]], 
     D[eqns[[3]], Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2]'[t]], 
     D[eqns[[3]], Subscript[\[CapitalPhi], 2]''[t]]}} // MatrixForm;
```

### Links I have used:

1. [Inverse problem for Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics)
2. [A Brief Review of Helmholtz Conditions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01563.pdf)
3. [Helmholtz conditions and the inverse problem for Lagrangian mechanics. P. 13](https://jfuchs.hotell.kau.se/kurs/amek/prst/19_heco.pdf)

Comment: Supposing that $g y-\dot z=c_0$ is a holonomous constraint, we can try $$L = \frac 12\left(\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2\right)+\frac 12\left(x-(y-z)\right)^2+\lambda(g y-\dot z-c_0)$$ with $\dot f = g$

Comment: @Cesareo `L = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2) + 1/2 (x[t] - (y[t] - z[t]))^2 + \[Lambda][t] (f'[t] y[t] - z'[t] - c0); D[D[L, x'[t]], t] - D[L, x[t]] // Simplify; D[D[L, y'[t]], t] - D[L, y[t]] // Simplify; D[D[L, z'[t]], t] - D[L, z[t]] // Simplify;` the equations of motion obtained through this Lagrangian do not coincide with the desired system. Do I need any additional manipulations with expression?

Comment: The whole manipulation is obtained with `L = 1/2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2) + 1/2 (x[t] - (y[t] - z[t]))^2 + lambda[t] (g[t] y[t] - z'[t] - c0);
equs0 = D[Grad[L, {x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]}], t] - Grad[L, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}];
equs1 = Join[equs0, {z''[t] - g'[t] y[t] - g[t] y'[t]}];
Solve[equs1 == 0, {x''[t], y''[t], z''[t], lambda'[t]}]` 
but even in this case, equation for $y''$ has an undesirable additional term.

Comment: @Cesareo if we consider this system of equations as a vector field, then the undesirable terms that arise after working with the Lagrangian are related to the nonconservative nature of this vector field. The question is how to treat these additional terms, perhaps as auxiliary "control signals". My point of view is that this vector field is the sum of the gradient of some potential field and an auxiliary vector of "control signals".